# Why does cost function increases over time? (OpenAI cartpole)

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow

I was trying the cartpole environment from OpenAI gym. The cost function goes up with time and the reward function goes down. I have no clue why it happens and how to solve it.

[[image]Top: Cost, bottom: Reward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtmFH.png)

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')

episodes = 1000
batchSize = 50
simulationSteps = 200
maxExperienceSize = 400
trainingSessions = 10
skip = 10
decimals = 2

# Hyper parameters
epsilon = 0.0
learningRate = 1e-4
gamma = .9

# Handles
state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,4],name='state')
action = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1],name='action')
nextQ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1],name='nextQ')

# Model
def model(state,action):    
    stateAction = tf.concat(1,[state,action],name='stateAction')

    weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,3]),name='weights1')
    weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,1]),name='weights2')

    activations1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(stateAction,weights1),name='activations1')
    activations2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(activations1,weights2),name='activations2')

    return activations2

prediction = model(state,action)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(prediction,nextQ))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learningRate).minimize(cost)

experience = []
avgRewards = []
costs = []

def getQValues(sess,s):
    fd = {state:[s],action:[[0.0]]}
    q0 = sess.run([prediction],fd)

    fd = {state:[s],action:[[1.0]]}
    q1 = sess.run([prediction],fd)

    return [q0[0],q1[0]]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for episode in range(episodes):
        env.reset()
        totalReward = 0
        resets = 1

        for t in range(simulationSteps):
            if len(experience) > maxExperienceSize:
                break

            lastState = tuple(np.around(env.state,decimals))

            # Take a random action
            a = env.action_space.sample()

            # Otherwise query the neural network
            if np.random.uniform() > np.exp(-epsilon):
                q = getQValues(sess,env.state)
                a = np.argmax(q)

            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(a)
            totalReward += reward
            qPrime = getQValues(sess,env.state)
            newQ = reward + gamma * max(qPrime)

            # Experience table
            row = (lastState,(a,),tuple(np.around(newQ[0],decimals)))            
            experience.append(row)

            if done:
                env.reset()
                resets += 1           

        # Remove duplicates
        experience = np.vstack({tuple(row) for row in experience})

        totalCost = 0
        for _ in range(trainingSessions):
            # Shuffle the experience
            np.random.shuffle(experience)

            # Get a batch
            batch = np.array(experience[:batchSize])         

            states = np.array(list(batch[:,0]))
            actions = np.array(list(batch[:,1]))    
            nextQs = np.array(list(batch[:,2]))

            fd = {state:states,action:actions,nextQ:nextQs}
            c,_ = sess.run([cost,optimizer],fd)

            totalCost += c

        experience = list(experience)

        # Forget half the experience
        if len(experience) >= maxExperienceSize:
            experience = experience[:int(maxExperienceSize/2)]

        epsilon += 2/(episodes)

        if episode % skip == 0:
            costs.append(totalCost/trainingSessions/batchSize)
            avgRewards.append(totalReward/resets)

            print(str(episode)+'\t'+str(costs[-1])+'\t'+str(avgRewards[-1])+'\t'
                  +str(len(experience)))



plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(costs)

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(avgRewards)
plt.show()
```

I decreased the learning rate from `1e-3` to `1e-4` but no luck.

EDIT 1:

Adding a bias term solved the cost issue but the reward just wont go up.

[image]

Comment: What do these plots represent? Cost and reward are the negative of each other, which the values in these plots are clearly not. Are they average reward over training episodes? Something else?

Comment: The top graph is training cost and the bottom graph is total reward divided by the number of restarts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through multiple solved examples and none of them try to solve it using this method. They use other methods like policy gradient or some kind of hill climbing. There is no problem with the code, but the problem is actually with the intuition. Q-learning works when the model satisfies the [Markov Property.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_property)

<s>The markov property states that the current state should have all information on how much reward can be acquired.</s> For the reward function to converge, the reward that can be obtained from each state should have a definite final value. That is not the case here. Let us take an example. Lets say when the needle is at 89 degrees, (90 degrees being straight up) it can go right to 91 degrees and then go back to 89 degrees. So, the number of times a particular state is traversed determines the total expected reward. Therefore, the reward function will not converge as there is no upper bound for the expected reward, from any state.

**EDIT**

Having a system of discounted rewards on losing works because now we have a tight upper and lower bounds of rewards. The agent gets a -1 on losing so it will try to stay as far as possible from a bad state. The ideal state or the upper bound of reward is now 0. Here is the modified code.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')

episodes = 500
batchSize = 100
simulationSteps = 500
maxExperienceSize = 600
trainingSessions = 6
skip = 10

# Hyper parameters
epsilon = 0.0
#learningRate = 1e-3
gamma = .9

# Handles
state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,4],name='state')
action = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1],name='action')
nextQ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1],name='nextQ')

# Model
def model(state,action):    
    stateAction = tf.concat(1,[state,action],name='stateAction')

    weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,3],0.1,1e-2),name='weights1')
    biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3],0.1,1e-2),name='biases1')

    weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,1],0.1,1e-2),name='weights2')
    biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1],0.1,1e-2),name='biases2')

    activations1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(stateAction,weights1)+biases1,name='activations1')
    #activations2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(activations1,weights2)+biases2,name='activations2')
    activations2 = tf.matmul(activations1,weights2)+biases2

    return activations2

prediction = model(state,action)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(prediction,nextQ))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

experience0 = []
experience1 = []
avgRewards = []
costs = []

def getQValues(sess,s):
    fd = {state:[s],action:[[0.0]]}
    q0 = sess.run([prediction],fd)

    fd = {state:[s],action:[[1.0]]}
    q1 = sess.run([prediction],fd)

    return np.array([float(q0[0][0]),float(q1[0][0])])

def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)

start = time.clock()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for episode in range(episodes):
        env.reset()
        totalReward = 0
        resets = 1       

        rows = []
        for t in range(simulationSteps):
            #if len(experience) > maxExperienceSize:
            #    break

            lastState = tuple(env.state)

            # Take a random action
            a = env.action_space.sample()

            q = getQValues(sess,env.state)
            # Otherwise query the neural network
            if np.random.uniform() > np.exp(-epsilon):
            #if False:                
                a = np.argmax(q)
                #a = np.random.choice(2,p=softmax(q))

            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(a)
            totalReward += reward

            rows.append([lastState,(a,),(0,)])

            if episode == episodes-1:
                print(q)
                env.render()
                time.sleep(.1)

            if done:
                env.reset()
                resets += 1

                for i in range(len(rows)-1,0,-1):
                    if i == len(rows)-1:
                        newQ = -1
                    else:
                        newQ = gamma * newQ

                    rows[i][2] = (newQ,)
                    #print(rows[i])

                # Experience table
                for row in rows:
                    forgetIndex = int(np.random.uniform(0,maxExperienceSize//2+1))
                    if a == 0:
                        experience0.append(tuple(row))
                        if len(experience0) > maxExperienceSize//2:
                            experience0.pop(forgetIndex)
                    else:
                        experience1.append(tuple(row))
                        if len(experience1) > maxExperienceSize//2:
                            experience1.pop(forgetIndex)
                rows = []

        # Remove duplicates
        #experience = np.vstack({tuple(row) for row in experience})

        # Get equal amounts of both experience
        dataSize = min(maxExperienceSize,len(experience0),len(experience1))
        experience = experience0[:dataSize] + experience1[:dataSize]        

        totalCost = 0
        for _ in range(trainingSessions):
            # Shuffle the experience
            np.random.shuffle(experience)

            # Get a batch
            batch = np.array(experience[:batchSize])         

            states = np.array(list(batch[:,0]))
            actions = np.array(list(batch[:,1]))    
            nextQs = np.array(list(batch[:,2]))

            fd = {state:states,action:actions,nextQ:nextQs}
            c,_ = sess.run([cost,optimizer],fd)

            totalCost += c

        if episode % skip == 0:
            elapsed = (time.clock() - start)/skip
            start = time.clock()
            print(elapsed * (episodes - episode)/60,' mins left')
            costs.append(totalCost/trainingSessions/batchSize)
            avgRewards.append(totalReward/resets)                
            print(len(experience0),len(experience1))
            print(str(episode)+'\t'+str(costs[-1])+'\t'+str(avgRewards[-1])+'\t'
                  +str(len(experience)))


        '''# Forget half the experience
        if len(experience0) >= maxExperienceSize/2:
            experience0 = experience0[:maxExperienceSize//4]

        if len(experience1) >= maxExperienceSize/2:
            experience1 = experience1[:maxExperienceSize//4]'''

        epsilon += 2/(episodes)

env.close()
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(costs)

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(avgRewards)
plt.show()
```

It is quite slow. Here is the new graph, top cost, bottom reward.

[image]

Comment: This second paragraph muddles several concepts involved in an MDP: RL methods in general assume the Markov property, but reward is by definition a function of $s, a, s'$. Put another way, by definition any state cannot possibly have "all information on how much reward can be acquired."

Comment: Isnt the definition of the value function, "how much reward can be obtained from this state and on wards?"

Comment: If by value function you mean the Bellman equation $V$, that's an intuitive way of describing it. Nevertheless, the first term in that equations is reward, which is in strict terms a function of current state, action, and the state arrived in. The Markov property specifies that the conditional distribution of future states depends only on the current state: It makes no statement or assumption regarding reward.

Comment: If the conditional distribution of future states depends only on the current state and the traversal of a state determines reward. Then how is not the distribution of rewards determined by the current state?

Comment: Of course it is, but that's not the Markov property: It's a consequence of the Markov property and the reward function. The Markov property per se entails no notion of reward. (NB that the term "reward" is fully absent from the wiki article.)

Comment: Oh, I thought it was naturally inferred, therefore omitted from the article. Anyway, thanks, fixed the answer.